# Which alternative electric connector is compatible with 12V plugs?

Tags: electronics, replacement-parts, connections, 12v

Which alternative commercial off-the-shelf electric connector matches with the LEGO 12V connector?
Are there for example mini-banana-plugs which match with the LEGO standard?